# VAE derivation for Gaussian case

Tags: normal-distribution, variational-bayes

In [Appendix B](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) of the VAE paper by Kingma and Welling, they derive the KL divergence for the scenario in which $q(\textbf{z})$ and $p(\textbf{z})$ are both Gaussian. I do not understand this step:

$$
\begin{align}
\int q_{\theta}(\textbf{z})\log p(\textbf{z}) d\textbf{z} 
&= \int \mathcal{N}(\textbf{z}; \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\sigma}^2) \log \mathcal{N}(\textbf{z}; \textbf{0}, \textbf{1})
\\
&= - \frac{J}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{J} (\mu_j^2 + \sigma_j^2)
\end{align}
$$

The first equality is fine. Can someone explain how to get from line 1 to 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\z}{\mathbf z}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}
\newcommand{\bmu}{\boldsymbol{\mu}}
\newcommand{\bsig}{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}$Expanding it out, and noting that the vectors here are $J$-dimensional and all the Gaussians here have diagonal covariances:
\begin{align}
     \int \mathcal{N}(\z; \bmu, \bsig^2) \log \mathcal{N}(\z; \mathbf 0, \mathbf 1) \, \mathrm{d}\z
  &= \E_{\z \sim \mathcal{N}(\bmu, \bsig^2)}\left[ \log\left( \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{J/2}} \exp\left( - \frac{1}{2} \lVert \z \rVert^2 \right) \right) \right]
\\&= -\frac{J}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac12 \E_{\mathbf z \sim \mathcal{N}(\bmu, \mathbf \bsig^2)}[ \lVert \z \rVert^2]
\\&= -\frac{J}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac12 \sum_{j=1}^J \E_{z_j \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \sigma_j^2)}[ z_j^2]
\\&= -\frac{J}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac12 \sum_{j=1}^J (\mu_j^2 + \sigma_j^2)
.\end{align}